# mongodb и память

Tags: python, django, mongodb, память

У меня приложение Django, использую mongoengine. Приложение часто выполняет aggregate запросы к базе. Все поля, по которым происходит $match, проиндексированы. Если необходимо, могу прикрепить примеры таких запросов.

Моя проблема в непонимании, как работает кэширование. После нескольких запросов к базе процесс mongod съедает всю память и после этого падает. В документации написано, что когда память кончается, то по принципу LRU должны тереться старые записи, и на их место ставиться новые.

Версия 3.2, движок стоит MMAPv1. Как написано в документации, для нормального кэширования достаточно примерно 'working set', т.е. dataSize + indexSize.
В моем случае это примерно 370Мб (290 dataSize, ~80 indexSize)

Мой my db.stats():

```
{
    "db" : "random_db",
    "collections" : 14,
    "objects" : 155613,
    "avgObjSize" : 1859.8720672437394,
    "dataSize" : 289420272,
    "storageSize" : 338821120,
    "numExtents" : 32,
    "indexes" : 22,
    "indexSize" : 82512192,
    "fileSize" : 1006632960,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 25,
        "totalSize" : 258314240
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Сервер VPS, на нем 1Гб оперативки, также я включил swap на 1Гб. Собственно этих 2 гигов хватает примерно на 70 запросов, каждый из которых заберает (!) 50 документов (использую $limit в pipeline-е). То есть около 3-4 тысяч документов в кэше весят более 2 Гигов, хоть вся база весит меньше 400 вместе с индексами.

Мой db.serverStatus.mem:

```
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 112,//Примерно такое значение при запуске сервиса, оно и растет
    "virtual" : 2523,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 1136,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 2272
}
```

Таким образом полагается, что больше 2523Мб кэш не может занять. Вот такого не получается. Вопрос довольно простой, но более конкретно в документации ничего не нашел, везде лишь написано "как должно быть".